# Reading user input into array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to store user input in an array, but I am having trouble accomplishing this.  Can anyone offer some advice?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeManagement {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Employee e = new Employee();
    Employee[] arrayOfEmp = new Employee[2];            //Fields
    public static int index;

    public void addRecord(Employee userE, int index){               //Add method
    while(index<arrayOfEmp.length){
        System.out.println("Please enter Employee Id : ");
        e.setEmployeeId(s.next());
        System.out.println("Please enter Employee Name : ");
        e.setName(s.next());
        this.arrayOfEmp[index]=userE;
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post your full code. It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

That should be because you don't append the right value in your array. You append "userE" which is a parameter, but you set values inside "e", which is another Employee instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
Employee[] arrayOfEmp = new Employee[2];            //Fields
public int index;

public int addRecord(int index){               //Add method
    while(index<arrayOfEmp.length){
      Employee e = new Employee();
      System.out.println("Please enter Employee Id : ");
      e.setEmployeeId(Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine()));
      System.out.println("Please enter Employee Name : ");
      e.setName(s.nextLine());
      this.arrayOfEmp[index++]=e;
      return index;
    }
```

to invoke it please use
    `index = addRecord(index);`
   then your variable index will be updated by local index var in method.

`s.next()` changed to `nextLine()`

Comment: +1 for dealing with a few different issues.  But I don't think it makes sense for `arrayOfEmp` to be non-static and `index` to be static, since `index` is the number of things you've already added to `arrayOfEmp`.  They should either both be non-static or both static.  Also, I don't think `index` should be passed into the method.

Answer (score 0):

Since, names for example [SUBASH PRAKASH] can be with spaces you have to use `nextLine()`.

For any other integers use `nextInt()`

And u should be calling using this as reference :  `Employee e = new Employee();`